# Get parent element from HTML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a following HTML and I want to fetch the parents in the document. I used Nokogiri for parsing:

```
j_text = "<p>
            <a>abc</a>
            <a>pqr></a>
         </p>
         <table>
           <tr>
             <td><p>example</p></td>
             <td><p>find</p></td>
             <td><p>by</p></td>
             <td><p>ID</p></td>
           </tr>
         </table>
        <p><p>zzzz</p>nnnnn</p>
        <u>sfds<u>"
```

I did:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(j_text)
```

Now I want the parent element from above HTML text i.e `<p>, <table>, <p>, <u>` using Nokogiri, how do I do this?

Comment: If you add some classes on parent nodes then you can try `doc.xpath('//p[@class="parent"]/text()')`

Comment: hey its returning empty array

Comment: or you can also try  `doc.css('p').children.remove` then will remove `children` and will give you parent node

Comment: @DeeptiKakade the above html doesn't looks valid. Are you sure you pasted correct code

Comment: @DeeptiKakade - Play around with `doc.xpath('//p')`

Comment: `doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('j_text')` `doc.at('p')`

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar  actually I have extracted this string from html and I want a parent tags in the document. I don't want only <p> tag

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar I just want to extract a parent element from the above example

Comment: The elements in your HTML document fragment have no parent.

Answer (score 12):

When you load that HTML fragment in Nokogiri it will automatically insert the elements into a root-level "html" element with a nested "body" element.

As such, the parent of the nodes in the HTML fragment you provided will be the "body":

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(j_text)
doc.root.name # => "html"
doc.xpath('//p').first.parent.name     # => "body"
doc.xpath('//table').first.parent.name # => "body"
doc.xpath('//u').first.parent.name     # => "body"
doc.to_html # =>
# <!DOCTYPE html...
# <html><body>
# <p>
#   <a>abc</a>
#   ...
```

Comment: I did with doc = Nokogiri::HTML(j_text).css('body').children